# Mercurial insert CURRENT revision number in files on hg archive

Tags: mercurial, version

I need the current version (version of the latest file) and it's tag to be included in files when I do hg archive.
When using keywords extension in includes the latest version of each file, not the current version.
Example:

```
repository contents:
file1  Jan 1st 2013 latest change tag v2.0
file2  Mar 1st 2013 latest change tag v1.0
```

What I need is to generate archive for v2.0 and automatically insert "v2.0" in each file, even if it hasn't been changed under 2.0 changeset.

Answer (score 2):

This is better done in your build/packaging/release system not in your source control system.  Since you're using `hg archive` (great choice) then theres a `.hg_archive.txt` file that's available to your packaging scripts or you can pass it to your release script as a parameter.

You're better off putting something like `VERSION_GOES_HERE` in your files and when you're archiving do:

```
LATEST_TAG="$(hg log --template '{latesttag}' -r)"
perl -pie "s/VERSION_GOES_HERE/${LATEST_TAG"
```

Comment: `hg log --template '{latesttag}' -r .` for variable

Comment: Keyword extension will **not** add latest tag *for repository* into single files